Azure logic App inserting data into DB2 table via on-prem gateway - LONG RUNNING
Inserting +- 21000 rows taking 5-6 hours
Current solution we have is a Azure logic app using db2 connector to insert rows into DB2 table (i-series) via on-prem gateway. More Concurrent connections improve only a little, not much

Welcome to stack overflow! This site is about programming questions. The programmer's approach to low bandwith and high latency network issues is to redesign the interface to the on-prem DB from single inserts to bulk import, e.g.: Export bulk data to one file, tranfer it to the destination DB and import it there. Or implement a service that is able to deal with bulk data. Did you try?

The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. Click here
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as Serverfault
, and Microsoft Q&A
for immediate help. Thanks!
